# Concurrent Hashmap clears itself.

Tags: java, wicket

I have a xml reader which reads the title and the name of a person in java from a rss feed. I accomplish this by using  document builder in java. When I read the element title and element name, I put them into a concurrent hashmap. This is fine, I can get the values from the map. However I want this information to be stored there for some time limit and not call the document builder until this time limit has passed. But the problem is when I do not call the document builder and refresh the webpage my hashmap values seem not to be stored. Code is in java and wicket.

Thoughts ?

Comment: No thoughts. Post the code, explain its execution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refreshing a wicket Panel in browser refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023100/refreshing-a-wicket-panel-in-browser-refresh)

Comment: That was it pretty much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that every time you're refreshing the page a new hashmap is built and the old one is simply discarded. You should make sure your data stays persistent.